# Как в значении поля записать результат деления двух полей другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, hive

Имеется Таблица1

```
Camp1 Camp2 Camp3 
2018  2019  2010
2000  2002  2015
1000  1000  1800
```

Имеется Таблица2

```
Camp1 Camp2 
ID    Результат
```

Подскажите выход: необходимо в Таблица2.Camp2 записать результат деления Таблица1.Camp1 на Таблица1.Camp2 при условии, что для числителя Camp3 больше 2009, а для знаменателя равное 2015.

Исходя из данных в ячейку нужно записать результат 2018/2002, так как условия для числителя выполняется в первой строке (2010>2009), а для знаменателя во второй (2015=2015). Таблица1 имеет уникальные строки, так что условие выполниться только один раз для знаменателя и числителя.

Заранее благодарю!

Версия серевера HIVE 2.2.0

Comment: Ну так покажите, какой именно результат нужно получить на показанных исходных данных! Конечно, при этом исходных бы добавить - чтобы показать и случай, когда условие выполняется, и случаи, когда нет.

Comment: пока прочитал условие - мозг вскипел, но так и не понял, когда делить нужно:)

Comment: Добавил пример на исходных данных

Comment: *Таблица1 имеет уникальные строки, так что условие выполниться только один раз для знаменателя и числителя.* Нет в этой фразе никакого "так что" - исходя из "объяснений", в таблицу 2 должны быть помещены 2 записи. Первая - показанная, вторая - "2000/2002". Ибо для числителя и условие 2015>2009 - выполняется.

Comment: Такое условие вас устроит? Вопрос в целом по фильтрации двух строк, а не в формулировке условий. Если есть указание того, что строки уникальны и условие выполнится только раз, то наверное так оно и есть

Comment: @ArtemReshetnikov не знаю, как для Akina, но мне условие так и не прояснилось...почему 2018 Вы взяли из строки1, а 2002 - из строки2?